# ReportViewer returns blank even if there exists data

Tags: c#, asp.net

My reportviewer returns blank when deployed. I have tried setting `AsyncRendering="false"` and `ShowParameterPrompts="true"`.

While setting AsyncRendering the report is loading but not properly,the control lost its width and no scroll appears, even the menu can't be seen.

Comment: Show some codes you used to generate the report.

Comment: It works fine in iis6 but returns blank in iis7... Code :  `<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rptReportViewer" runat="server" Height="470px" Width="100%" AsyncRendering="false" ShowCredentialPrompts="False" ShowDocumentMapButton="False" ShowFindControls="False" ShowParameterPrompts="False" ShowPromptAreaButton="False" ShowZoomControl="False"  BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" ShowBackButton="True" SizeToReportContent="true"> </rsweb:ReportViewer>`